# Tensorflow: How to Propagate Gradient Through tf.gather?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having some issues trying to propagate the gradient of my loss function with respect to a variable that represents the gather index, similar to what is done in spatial transformer networks (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/transformer/spatial_transformer.py). I feel like I might be missing something very simple. Here is a simplified toy example of what I would want to do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
lf = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0])
lf_b = 2.0
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(3))
pt = tf.Variable(0, name='point')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=())
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
y = tf.gather(x, pt)
data_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y,y_))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(data_loss)
```

Currently, this returns the error: 
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

Comment: I'm also interested in how to make tf.gather differentiable (if possible). Have you @user873261 been able to sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't differentiate since pt is an integer.  It is selecting one index in the x placeholder so it does not have a derivative.  Normally when you do this you would input an integer and use this to select a floating point value.  You are doing it the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My understanding is that according to (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02025v3.pdf) and the code in (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/transformer/spatial_transformer.py), this sort of sampling should be (sub)-differentiable. Even when pt is a float (which is later rounded and cast as an int), I get the same error. Do you have a suggestion for how this should work?