# How can I make TensorFlow 2.0 handle piecewise gradients (e.g. across `tf.gather`)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm attempting to leverage TensorFlow 2.0's automatic differentiation to automate the calculation of certain gradients on financial instruments. Generally this involves a piecewise interpolation scheme between various "benchmark points". The simplest example is below:

```py
    import tensorflow as tf

    MATURITIES = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 10.0, 12.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0])
    CASH_FLOW_TIMES = tf.constant([n * 0.5 for n in range(1, 51)])
    YIELDS = tf.Variable([0.04153733, 0.0425888, 0.04662959, 0.05406879, 0.05728735, 0.0606996, 0.06182699, 0.05854381, 0.05376556, 0.0531946])

    @tf.function
    def linear(knot_y, knot_x, x):
        """Linear interpolation"""
        i = tf.maximum(tf.minimum(tf.searchsorted(knot_x, x, side="right") - 1, knot_x.shape[0] - 2), 0)
        y_i = tf.gather(knot_y, i)
        x_i = tf.gather(knot_x, i)
        return y_i + y_i / x_i * (x - x_i)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(YIELDS)
        y = linear(YIELDS, MATURITIES, CASH_FLOW_TIMES)
    dydx = tape.gradient(y, YIELDS)
    y, dydx
```

Which outputs the following:

```py
    (<tf.Tensor: id=1249, shape=(50,), dtype=float32, numpy=
     array([0.02076866, 0.04153733, 0.06230599, 0.0425888 , 0.053236  ,
            0.04662959, 0.05440119, 0.06217279, 0.06994438, 0.05406879,
            0.05947567, 0.06488255, 0.07028943, 0.05728735, 0.0613793 ,
            0.06547125, 0.06956321, 0.07365517, 0.07774712, 0.0606996 ,
            0.06373458, 0.06676956, 0.06980454, 0.06182699, 0.06440312,
            0.06697924, 0.06955536, 0.07213148, 0.07470761, 0.05854381,
            0.06049527, 0.06244673, 0.06439819, 0.06634965, 0.06830111,
            0.07025257, 0.07220403, 0.07415549, 0.07610695, 0.05376556,
            0.0551097 , 0.05645384, 0.05779798, 0.05914212, 0.06048626,
            0.06183039, 0.06317453, 0.06451868, 0.06586281, 0.06720695],
           dtype=float32)>,
     <tensorflow.python.framework.indexed_slices.IndexedSlices at 0x203027345c0>)
```

The issue is that, due (I suspect) to the `tf.searchsorted` or `tf.gather` calls, the gradient is an `IndexedSlice`, not a Tensor. This causes an issue when I need to chain multiple `tf.function` together to value a security. For example, say I want to use a transformation of the `YIELDS` variable within my `linear` function:

```py
    import tensorflow as tf

    MATURITIES = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 10.0, 12.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0])
    CASH_FLOW_TIMES = tf.constant([n * 0.5 for n in range(1, 51)])
    YIELDS = tf.Variable([0.04153733, 0.0425888, 0.04662959, 0.05406879, 0.05728735, 0.0606996, 0.06182699, 0.05854381, 0.05376556, 0.0531946])

    @tf.function
    def logdf_from_yields(yields, times):
        return tf.math.multiply(yields, times) * -1.0

    @tf.function
    def linear(knot_y, knot_x, x):
        """Linear interpolation"""
        i = tf.maximum(tf.minimum(tf.searchsorted(knot_x, x, side="right") - 1, knot_x.shape[0] - 2), 0)
        y_i = tf.gather(knot_y, i)
        x_i = tf.gather(knot_x, i)
        return y_i + y_i / x_i * (x - x_i)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(YIELDS)
        y = linear(logdf_from_yields(YIELDS, MATURITIES), MATURITIES, CASH_FLOW_TIMES)
    dydx = tape.gradient(y, YIELDS)
    y, dydx
```

This code raises the following exception:

```py
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-9-2bc3457894ea> in <module>
         20     tape.watch(YIELDS)
         21     y = linear(logdf_from_yields(YIELDS, MATURITIES), MATURITIES, CASH_FLOW_TIMES)
    ---> 22 dydx = tape.gradient(y, YIELDS)
         23 y, dydx

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\backprop.py in gradient(self, target, sources, output_gradients, unconnected_gradients)
       1000         output_gradients=output_gradients,
       1001         sources_raw=flat_sources_raw,
    -> 1002         unconnected_gradients=unconnected_gradients)
       1003 
       1004     if not self._persistent:

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\imperative_grad.py in imperative_grad(tape, target, sources, output_gradients, sources_raw, unconnected_gradients)
         74       output_gradients,
         75       sources_raw,
    ---> 76       compat.as_str(unconnected_gradients.value))

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in backward_function(*args)
        904               if a is not None and i not in skip_positions]
        905       return self._backward_graph_function._call_flat(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    --> 906           list(args) + side_outputs)
        907 
        908     tape.record_operation(self._forward_function.signature.name, real_outputs,

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args)
        610     if any(isinstance(a, composite_tensor.CompositeTensor) for a in args):
        611       raise AssertionError("Expected all args to be Tensors or Variables; "
    --> 612                            "but got CompositeTensor: %r" % args)
        613 
        614     if (tape.could_possibly_record() or

    AssertionError: Expected all args to be Tensors or Variables; but got CompositeTensor: [<tensorflow.python.framework.indexed_slices.IndexedSlices object at 0x00000203013C2128>, <tf.Tensor: id=1024, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-1.0>, <tf.Tensor: id=1025, shape=(10,), dtype=float32, numpy=
    array([0.04153733, 0.0851776 , 0.13988876, 0.27034396, 0.40101147,
           0.606996  , 0.74192387, 0.87815714, 1.0753112 , 1.329865  ],
          dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: id=1026, shape=(10,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  7., 10., 12., 15., 20., 25.], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: id=1027, shape=(10,), dtype=float32, numpy=
    array([0.04153733, 0.0425888 , 0.04662959, 0.05406879, 0.05728735,
           0.0606996 , 0.06182699, 0.05854381, 0.05376556, 0.0531946 ],
          dtype=float32)>]
```

Inspecting the traceback, I see that the only item that is not a Tensor or Variable is the IndexedSlice, which I believe, again, comes from the `linear` function.

Is there a way for me to rewrite the piecewise `linear` function (e.g. using different functions) so that it will work with the gradient tape?

**What have I tried?**

I took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548871/tensorflow-how-to-propagate-gradient-through-tf-gather), but it seemed like the writer was trying to make the index a variable. Here I should know all of my indices ahead of time (i.e. because `MATURITIES` and `CASH_FLOW_TIMES` are fixed for any given instance of the problem ... only `YIELDS` is a `tf.Variable`). So I wasn't so sure how it applied.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50301565/function-gradients-with-gather-operations-in-tensorflow) was also interesting in that it recommended the usage of `tf.convert_to_tensor`, but I'm not sure how to apply it in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your gradient seems to be fine. TensorFlow uses [`tf.IndexedSlices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/IndexedSlices) to represent sparse gradients in some cases like [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather), but you can easily convert it to a regular tensor like this (the example is in graph mode but the function would be the same in eager mode):

```
import tensorflow as tf

def convert_indexed_slices_to_tensor(idx_slices):
    return tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(idx_slices.indices, 1),
                         idx_slices.values, idx_slices.dense_shape)

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.constant([1., 2., 3., 4.])
    b = tf.gather(a, [0, 2])
    g = tf.gradients(b, a)[0]
    print(g)
    # IndexedSlices(indices=..., values=..., dense_shape=...)
    g_dense = convert_indexed_slices_to_tensor(g)
    # Tensor(...)
    print(sess.run(g_dense))
    # [1. 0. 1. 0.]
```

---

If you want to force [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) to produce regular tensors, you can wrap it with [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient) like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.custom_gradient
def gather_dense_gradient(params, indices, validate_indices=None, name=None):
    def grad(ys):
        return tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(indices, 1), ys, tf.shape(params)), None
    return tf.gather(params, indices, validate_indices, name), grad

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.constant([1., 2., 3., 4.])
    b = gather_dense_gradient(a, [0, 2])
    g = tf.gradients(b, a)[0]
    print(sess.run(g))
    # [1. 0. 1. 0.]
```

Note this assumes `axis=0` and one-dimensional `indices`, otherwise it would still be possible to do the same but it would require a bit more of work.

Comment: Ok, so it seems like `convert_to_tensor` is the way to go. Is there a way to force `tf.gather` to use `tf.Tensor` instead of `tf.IndexedSlices` to represent gradients? I'd rather not move too far away from the current functional decomposition or program flow.

Comment: @MikeRand Ah, you're right, actually [`tf.convert_to_tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) does already implement conversion from [`tf.IndexedSlices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/IndexedSlices). I have updated the answer with a possible workaround using [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient).